# Create implementation of Java class dynamically based on provided dependencies at runtime

Tags: java

I'm trying to determine the best way to create a new instance of a class based on which classes are available on the classpath at runtime.

For example, I have a library that requires a JSON response to be parsed in multiple classes. The library has the following interface:

`JsonParser.java`:

```
public interface JsonParser {
    <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> type);
    <T> String toJson(T object);
}
```

This class has multiple implementations, i.e. `GsonJsonParser`, `JacksonJsonParser`, `Jackson2JsonParser`, and currently, the user of the library is required to "pick" their implementation to be used based on which library they've included in their project. For example:

```
JsonParser parser = new GsonJsonParser();
SomeService service = new SomeService(parser);
```

What I'd like to do, is dynamically pick up which library is on the classpath, and create the proper instance, so that the user of the library doesn't have to think about it (or even have to know the internal implementation of another class parses JSON).

I'm considering something similar to the following:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.google.gson.Gson");
    return new GsonJsonParser();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Gson isn't on classpath, try next implementation
}

try {
    Class.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper");
    return new Jackson2JsonParser();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Jackson 2 was not found, try next implementation
}

// repeated for all implementations

throw new IllegalStateException("You must include either Gson or Jackson on your classpath to utilize this library");
```

Would this be an appropriate solution? It seems kind of like a hack, as well as uses exceptions to control the flow.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I agree, it is a *hack*. Pick one JSON parser dependency and use it? Your approach also *might* become unexpectedly **non-deterministic**; depending on the JARs (and possibly the order of the JARs in the class-path) the program behavior could change.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'd like to do that, but currently the applications that would be using this have any one of those parsers, and I'm trying to avoid having a second one become a dependency if it's different than the one that I decided to package (or same library, different version).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It seems it isn't such hack, see my answer where I gave link to Spring's implementation of same issue.

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, Spring does it too; it's still a *hack*. I will even concede it appears to be a *clever hack*. But, if Java 9+ adds a built-in JSON parser, then it *retroactively* becomes?

Comment: @Casey How do you get the implementations to compile when the classes on classpath are missing?

Comment: @TomášZato, I'm including them as provided dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially you want to create your own `JsonParserFactory`. We can see how it's implemented in the [Spring Boot framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/10012cfddc5479ee9a5cbe98bfe4f76483965bd1/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/json/JsonParserFactory.java#L40-L57):

```
public static JsonParser getJsonParser() {
    if (ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", null)) {
        return new JacksonJsonParser();
    }
    if (ClassUtils.isPresent("com.google.gson.Gson", null)) {
        return new GsonJsonParser();
    }
    if (ClassUtils.isPresent("org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml", null)) {
        return new YamlJsonParser();
    }

    return new BasicJsonParser();
}
```

So your approach is nearly the same as this, except for the use of the [`ClassUtils.isPresent` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L325-L334).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like [that's exactly what ClassUtils is doing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L325-L334). So maybe I wasn't _completely_ off-base.

Comment: @Casey you are absolutely right, I missed the fact that `ClassUtils` itself is part of Spring, so I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a perfect case for the [Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) pattern. Check out the [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) documentation for an example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 5):

If only one of the implementations (`GsonJsonParser`, `JacksonJsonParser`, `Jackson2JsonParser`) would be present at runtime and there is no other option, then you'd have to use `Class.forName()`.

Although you can handle it a smarter.
For example, you can put all the classes into a `Set<String>` and then loop over them. If any one of them throws exception, you can just continue, and the one which does not, you can do your operations.

Yes, it is a hack, and your code would become library dependent. If there could be any chance that you can include all three implementations of your JsonParsers in your classpath and use a logic to define which implementation you have to use; that would be a much better approach.

If this is not possible, you can continue with above.

---

Also, instead of using plain `Class.forName(String name)`, you can use a better option `Class.forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)` which will NOT run any static initializers (if present in your class).

Where `initialize = false` and `loader = [class].getClass().getClassLoader()`

Answer (score 4):

The simple approach is the one SLF4J uses: create a separate wrapper library per underlying JSON library (GSON, Jackson, etc.) with a `com.mypackage.JsonParserImpl` class that delegates to the underlying library. Put the appropriate wrapper in the classpath alongside the underlying library. Then you can get the current implementation like:

```
public JsonParser getJsonParser() {
    // needs try block
    // also, you probably want to cache
    return Class.forName("com.mypackage.JsonParserImpl").newInstance()
}
```

This approach uses the class loader to locate the JSON parser. It is the simplest and requires no 3rd party dependencies or frameworks. I see no drawbacks to it relative to Spring, Service Provider, or any other method of locating resources.

---

Alternately use the Service Provider API, as Daniel Pryden suggests. To do this, you still create a separate wrapper library per underlying JSON library. Each library includes a text file at location "META-INF/services/com.mypackage.JsonParser" whose contents is the fully qualified name of the implementation of `JsonParser` in that library. Then your `getJsonParser` method would look like:

```
public JsonParser getJsonParser() {
    return ServiceLoader.load(JsonParser.class).iterator().next();
}
```

IMO this approach is unnecessarily more complex than the first.

Comment: Interesting solution, definitely sounds like a better and more maintainable option than the one I proposed. I tested out the Service Provider API and it doesn't seem any more complex really, just a tad annoying to have to add that file in `META-INF` of each wrapper. I do like that it allows the classes to keep a different name, i.e. `GsonJsonParser` and `JacksonJsonParser` instead of `JsonParserImpl`, but that's purely semantic I suppose...